# return nodes with selected properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using a graph database having many nodes connected to a super node by a relationship TYPE. And each of those sub nodes have properties via a  FROM relationship.
How should i access the properties of individual nodes in cypher query?

I tried this but its not working.

```
start a=node(2) match (a)<-[:TYPE]-(node) match (node)<-[:FROM]-(prop) where prop.name="ABC" return node;
```

Here i have to return a node with a property `name` whose value is ABC!?
How should i correct it?

Comment: Could specify your data better? some cypher to create sample data would be ideal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
START a=node(2) 
MATCH (a)<-[:TYPE]-(node)<-[:FROM]-(prop)
WHERE prop.name="ABC" 
RETURN node;
```

You could also do this using indexes:

```
START a=node:properties('name:ABC')
MATCH (node)<-[:FROM]-(a)
```

Where 'properties' is your index which indexes name as 'ABC'. Realize that your above query is only interested in the node related with :FROM, therefore searching in the first example could be very long compared to simply using indexing.

If you are using Neo4j 2.x, then you are far better off with labels.

```
MATCH (a:Property(name='ABC'))-[:FROM]->(node)
RETURN node
```

Where you would set the label 'Property' when you create/update a property node.